# I'm stuck with firebase and angular

Tags: angular, angularfire2, angularfire

I'm sorry to repeat myself. But I'm really stuck in here.

[image]

I want to access the zip property in the address object.

But the address object in another object(message).

Here is the code I already try.

The Ts fire:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatService } from '../services/chat.service';
import { chatMessegeModel } from '../models/chat-message.model';
import {  AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 
 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-feed',
   templateUrl: './feed.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./feed.component.css']
 })
export class FeedComponent implements OnInit {
  feed: AngularFireObject<chatMessegeModel[]>;
   details: Observable<any>


 constructor(
   private chat: ChatService,
   private db: AngularFireDatabase
  ) { 
   this.details = this.db.list('message',
    ref=> ref.limitToLast(25)
    ).valueChanges();

   }

   ngOnInit() {
   }

}
```

And the HTML file:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of details | async"> 

   <div *ngFor="let address of (item.address | async)"> 
      <p>
          {{address.zip}}
       </p>
   </div>

</div>
```

But I can't access the zip property

Comment: I think you want `let item of details | async` to start. Also, you can't do `ngFor` on address because it's not an array. Can you try just `{{item.address.zip}}` please?

Comment: sorry it's actually details

Comment: No the console say:
Cannot read property 'zip' of undefined

Comment: Okay, can you do `{{ item | json }}`, and let us know the output please?

Comment: { "email": "rakiubl97@gmail.com", "message": "What", "timeStand": "2018/8/27 20:3:51", "username": "Rakibul" }

{ "email": "rakiubl97@gmail.com", "message": "What's Up?", "timeStand": "2018/8/27 20:3:57", "username": "Rakibul" }

{ "email": "rakiubl97@gmail.com", "message": "Helo", "timeStand": "2018/8/27 20:25:37", "username": "Rakibul" }

{ "address": { "place": "Jhenaidah", "street": 2, "zip": 7300 }, "email": "rakiubl97@gmail.com", "message": "hi", "timeStand": "2018/8/27 20:25:40", "username": "Rakibul" }

Comment: Okay, from that it looks like `item` is an array as well, so `ngFor` through that as well `*ngFor="let something of item"` and then get the address `{{something?.address?.zip}}`. We're using `?` here because not all of the items have an address from the looks of it

Comment: the console say:
Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Conditional expression item?address?.zip requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression [ {{item?address?.zip}} ]

Comment: Youre missing the `.`s after the `?`s

Comment: The html:
<div *ngFor="let item of details">
   <p>
       {{item?.address?.zip}}
   </p>
 </div>

And The console:
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: OOO god.. I get it...
Thanks a lot.... :)

Comment: Just One More thing:
 https://files.fm/u/r8mfvkmg
check The Image. What if i have this type of object like address and i want to access all name in the address object at Once

Comment: It depends what the object structure is. I assume instead of `people` and `z` the keys could be anything? What do you want to do with the names? Should be be comma separated or something?